# Calling substitute() and expand() inside new command definition in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to define a new command in Vim that calls an external script with the name of the current file, but slightly modified. Here's how I defined the command:

```
:command MyNewCommand !/tmp/myscript.sh substitute(expand("%:p"), "-debug", "", 'g')
```

In other words, `myscript.sh` takes one parameter, which is the full pathname of the file being edited, with the string `-debug` in the pathname removed. My command definition doesn't work because rather than passing the pathname, Vim seems to pass to `myscript.sh` the entire string itself, beginning with the word `substitute`. How do I define the command to do what I want? Thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `system()` function to execute the script.
Change the command definition as follows:

```
:command! MyNewCommand call system('/tmp/myscript.sh ' .
\   shellescape(substitute(expand('%:p'), '-debug', '', 'g')))
```

To see the output of the command, replace `call` with `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use solution similar to @ib's one, but with `!` which will show you the output of the shell command (and will also handle case when `expand('%:p')` contains newlines (it can if FS is fully POSIX-compliant)):

```
command MyNewCommand execute '!/tmp/myscript.sh' shellescape(substitute(expand('%:p'), '-debug', '', 'g'))
```

Comment: Did you try to run the command?  It does not work for filenames that contain newlines!  It is not surprising since Vim help states that 'A newline character ends {cmd}, what follows is interpreted as a following ":" command.  However, if there is a backslash before the newline it is removed and {cmd} continues.' (cf. `:h :!`).  So, at least it is necessary to escape the filename using `shellescape()` function.  By the way, using `system()` with proper quoting of filenames (single quotes around them work for Bash) works in most of the cases.

Comment: @ib: did you run it on a filename with newline characters? Gasp! +1 for the reference to `shellescape` though :)

Comment: @sehe:  Yes, to be sure I did `$ echo OK >"$(printf 'a\nb')"`, `$ echo FAIL >a`, then did `:exe '!cat ' "a\nb"` and `:exe '!cat ' shellescape("a\nb")` in Vim.

Comment: @ib It works normally with NL characters if you add `shellescape(...)` (I just forgot to write it and wrote first paragraph with the assumption that I will write shellescape() in the code snippet). It won't do so with `system()`: `execute "echo a > ".shellescape("a\nb")` leaves me with file `a$'\n'b` which is correct, while `call system("echo b > ".shellescape("a\nb"))` leaves me with `a\\$'\n'b`. This weird behavior is documented (first `Note` in `:h system()`).

Comment: @ZyX:  It works with `shellescape()` indeed.  If you quote a filename properly (according to your shell syntax)--as I point in my first comment--in most cases you can also use `system()` call.  For example, try `:call system("echo TEST >'a\nb'")`.

Comment: @ib I know that. But in this case you will need to add different shells support: `a'b`, for example, may be quoted as `'a'\''b'` (POSIX shell, zsh), `'a''b'` (zsh with rcquotes set (unlikely to happen as normal user will put this into ~/.zshrc that is not sourced for non-interactive shells)), `"a'b"` (cmd.exe). `shellescape()` cares about this, I don't know why `system()` call is spoiled in this case, but I would not write `call system("echo TEST > 'a\nb'")`, as there is `execute "silent! !echo TEST > ".fnameescape("a\nb")` if you don't need to output anything.

Answer (score 1):

The generic approach is to build a string and then `execute` it. The problem in your command is that  `substitute(expand(...` is not being evaluated and it's passed as is.

So in a generic example

```
command MyNewCommand OldCommand expand("%:p")
```

should be converted to

```
command MyNewCommand execute 'OldCommand '.expand("%:p")
```

That way `MyNewCommand` will just invoke [`execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) with the expression `'OldCommand '.expand("%:p")`. `execute` will evaluate the expression and therefore `expand()` will get evaluated to the filename and concatenated to `'OldCommand '` resulting in a string of the form `'OldCommand myfilename'`. That string then gets executed as an `Ex` command by the same `execute`.